# Has the monarchy in the UK delegated even its symbolic power to the government, or does it still retain its symbolic power?

Tags: united-kingdom, constitutional-monarchy

I quote three excerpts from the same article in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchy_of_the_United_Kingdom):

> Though the ultimate executive authority over the government is still formally by and through the royal prerogative, these powers may only be used according to laws enacted in Parliament and, in practice, within the constraints of convention and precedent.

This seems to imply that the government fulfill, as it were, the will of royal prerogative by legislating.

Next paragraph:

> The authority to use the sovereign's formal powers is almost all delegated, either by statute or by convention, to ministers or officers of the Crown, or other public bodies. Thus the acts of state done in the name of the Crown, such as Crown Appointments, even if personally performed by the monarch, such as the Queen's Speech and the State Opening of Parliament, depend upon decisions made elsewhere.

Once again, this implies to me that the ministers and other public bodies are appropriating the sovereign's inherent authority.

However, see paragraph No. 3:

> Although the royal prerogative is extensive and parliamentary approval is not formally required for its exercise, it is limited. Many Crown prerogatives have fallen out of use or have been permanently transferred to Parliament.

So which is it? does the crown still retain symbolic authority, with (almost) all practical power in the hands of the government? Or is even the *symbolic* authority no longer in the hands of the monarch?

Comment: If it's symbolic, it doesn't matter anyway. That is the definition of symbolic, or not?

Comment: Most executive authority in western nations is symbolically lodged in someone or some thing - e.g a flag, a constitution, the corpus known anodynely as "the people", or - in countries that are still monarchies - the crown. In the UK criminal actions are listed as *Crown versus Jones*, in the US as *People versus Jones* - but to all intents they amount to the same thing. For an answer to "What is a sovereign?" read Hobbes *Leviathan*, published 1651.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "symbolic authority"? I'm afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff well clearly what is meant is not actual or real authority, but merely an appearance of authority. Vast numbers of government institutions are in Britain prefaced HM e.g HMRC (Her Majesty's Revenue Commissioners - who levy and manage taxes), HM Prison - Wormwood Scrubs, and unbelievably "The Keeper of the Queen's Swans" whose job is to ensure the protection of swans.  The swans do not literally belong to the Queen, but symbolically they do and are protected.

Comment: @Trilarion Symbolic power can have practical ramifications. I'll admit I can't think of any but imagine, for argument's sake, some religious ritual requires the act of a ruling monarch (outside the powers of royal prerogative). Would a symbolic act by HM suffice? Or even on a symbolic level, no act performed by the queen would have any significance?

Comment: @WS2 I completely agree but regarding the UK in particular, I am asking if the queen herself is the embodiment of executive authority, or just the general monarchy?

Comment: Clearly it is the Queen herself - but there is a recognised line of succession to the throne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three parties involved here, not two. The three parties are the monarch, the government (prime minister) and parliament.

The power struggle between monarch and parliament permeatues English/British history. Parliament acquired more and more powers, often at least in a semi-codified way. The existence of a clearly defined group of ministers forming a government came later. These were chosen by the monarch initially (and taken to be on the side of the monarch in whatever powerstruggles there might be), with the requirement for parliament consent only coming later.

The current situation is that the monarch has lost a lot of their power to parliament (enough to make the UK a consitutational monarchy anyway). "Royal prerogative" describes powers the monarch retains vis-a-vis parliament. However, in a secondary development the monarch has also surrendered control over actually wielding this power to the government.

Comment: This is a good summary, but the last sentence is not right. Parliament has never (at least in recent times) had the power to determine when a session ends (i.e. when it is prorogued); that has long been solely in the hands of the monarch, on the "advice" of the PM. The issue was whether a court could quash the "advice", and hence cancel the prorogation - or whether, being a prerogative matter, it was beyond the powers of the court to intervene.

Comment: Please also add some references.

Comment: "the monarch has also lost surrendered control over actually wielding this power to the government" I don't fully understand this sentence. What is "lost surrendered control" and what is "actually wielding his power to the government"? Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff The point at issue was the nature of the prorogation - for far longer than was normally the case, and clearly for the purpose of avoiding the government's accountability to parliament.  The proceedings in the Supreme Court, which in a unanimous judgement held the prorogation to be unlawful,  revealed thet the Prime Minister had wrongly, and hence unlawfully, advised the Queen that the prorogation was proper.

Comment: @WS2: yes, I agree. My point is that the last sentence of the answer is inaccurate.

Comment: @Trilarion I hadn't decided whether to use "lost" or "surrendered". I've removed "lost" now. Last paragraph removed for now, I'll see whether I can revise the formulation and readd eventually.

Comment: The UK Monarch has neither "lost" or "surrendered" its [powers to vet and alter laws before they are debated in parliament](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2021/feb/08/royals-vetted-more-than-1000-laws-via-queens-consent).

Comment: @User65535 All that that article seemed to me to do was indicate that the Queen has prime lobbying power with the government about anything which affects her or her family. It is perhaps not unreasonable that if the Queen is expected assent to Acts of Parliament, which she is so expected - albeit symbolically - that she should be advised about ones that are in the pipeline. I would be seriously concerned if she refused assent to an Act, but I think the last monarch to do that was Queen Anne, who died in 1714 - long before there was such a thing as a USA.

Comment: The Guardian is a good newspaper, but like all journalism it earns it living with eye-catching headlines.

Comment: The point is that we do not know what she has changed.  Until these freedom of information requests we had no idea she was consulted on over 1,000 laws ranging from justice, social security, pensions, race relations and food policy through to obscure rules on car parking charges and hovercraft. Just because you do not care does not mean she has "surrendered control over actually wielding this power to the government."

Comment: @User65535: there are two different issues at play here. (1) Queen's Consent - which is different from Royal Assent - but which it appears to be just as much of a formality; from that Guardian article: "Queen’s consent is a parliamentary process, with the role of sovereign purely formal. Consent is always granted by the monarch where requested by government."

Comment: (2) Influence: that's not a formal power, merely a side effect of the fact that she's the Queen, and gets to speak to the PM on a regular basis. Obviously it's debatable whether the monarch should be able to lean on the PM in that way; but it's different from the many _de jure_ powers that monarch has, but no longer exercises personally.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff "...the many de jure powers that monarch has, but no longer exercises ..." Presumably because not enough people believe that these powers should be wielded that way, but then one could also just get rid of them and simplify matters. Otherwise it looks a bit like a monarchy in waiting. Or is it really just ornamental and it's understood that at the very moment the monarch actually uses any power these powers will get retracted. I guess this is what this question is about.

Comment: @Arno I accept your point that seeing as the Royal authority was never ceded willingly, it makes no sense to assume that symbolic rule remained in the hands of the monarchy. At least, that's how I understand your answer.

Comment: @WS2 Queen Anne's failure to give royal assent to the [Scottish Militia Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Militia_Bill) in 1708 was on the advice of her ministers.  They changed their opinion on the desirability of the bill between it leaving parliament and arriving at the Queen's desk because they were worried about news of a possible French invasion.

Comment: @Henry Interesting. So when was the last time a monarch on their own initiative, and for their own resons refused assent to a bill?

Comment: @WS2 Possibly one of the six times William III did it (so not that much earlier), as he took a more personal view having become king by conquest.  Anne (and later monarchs such as George III) were more likely to change the ministers who advised them if they were unhappy with something. There were more and later cases of assent being withheld in British colonies (including the 13 that became the United States), though these were all disputes between the British government or its appointed governors and the colonial assemblies rather than the personal intervention of the monarch.